# Python function to return column values from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pandas

I want to create a function with two arguments which return some specific name from a Names column.  The first argument is an existing dataframe and the second argument is name.  I know how to pull specific values from rows but putting it in multi-argument functions is my issue:

```
def returnDataForOneName(namesDF, name):
    for string in name:
    ?--> return [string.values() for string in namesDF]
```

I would like to test the function with one of my existing csv files:

```
  import pandas as pd
    datapath = 'C:\Users\namefile.csv'
    namesDF = pd.read_csv(datapath) 
    newDF = returnDataForOneName(nameDF, 'Tim')
```

Comment: Given a name, you want to .... return names? What names do you want to return? Can you explain what you're trying to do? There are many things wrong here, I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a simple index, no need for a function:

```
newDf = nameDf[nameDf['name'] == 'Tim']]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I wanted to have a function where a user could return any name they typed into the function, how could I do that?

Comment: If you wanted to return any name, you could use the input() function  in Python 3 to collect input from the user and then replace "Tim" with your input variable. [input() function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)